# Выбор конкретного объекта с одинаковыми классами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо при наведении курсора получить конкретный элемент с классом (.b), а не все элементы сразу.

А я получаю все сразу:

```js
 
 $(".a").hover(function() {
        $(".b").css({"position":"relative","top":"0px"});
 }, function() {
  $(".b").css({"position":"relative","top":"-40px"});
 });
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: у Вас специально тег `div` не закрыт или случайно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `$('.b')` нужно использовать `$(this).find('.b')`

Comment: Спасибо, children не помог $(this).find('.b') помогло!

Comment: @MaxPolsky как это children не помог?) вы нас обманываете) пример на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cye5ohbm/

Comment: Я подставил значение, скрипт не заработал, смысл мне обманывать, смешной ты! Может в другой раз сработает, я написал как есть!

Comment: @MaxPolsky Возможно для Вас же будет полезнее понять почему фукнция children() у Вас не сработала, а на реальном примере с Вашим же кодом, она работает правильно. Вы же смотрели ссылку с примером?

Comment: Да, смотрел, но у меня она не работала! а .find сработала.

Comment: Может дело в версии jQuery

Comment: Врятли 1.11 стоит а children доступен с 1.0 версии, не знаю почему.

Comment: я заменил кож jquery в примере выше и выходит вообще какая то фигня. Так что children не помогло бы полюбому! $(".a").hover(function() {
  $(this).children(".b").css({
    "color": "red",
    "top": "0px"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).children(".b").css({
    "pcolor": "black",
    "top": "0px"
  });
}); - вот такой поставь код @Alex

Comment: @MaxPolsky вероятно не `pcolor`, а `color`. Посмотрите **[пример работы на версии 1.11](http://jsfiddle.net/zyopc0gv/)**.  уточните пожалуйста, а тег **<div>** у Вас специально не закрыт? 
`<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
<div>` - на конце должен быть **<div>** или **</div>**?

Comment: Поторопился, там должен быть </div> я даже не сразу заметил!

Comment: @MaxPolsky уточните пожалуйста у Вас наш ответ с children() сейчас работает(с учетом </div>) ? или **[пример работы для смены цвета](http://jsfiddle.net/zyopc0gv/)** ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию **[children()](http://jquery-docs.ru/Traversing/children/)**

```js
$(".a").hover(function() {
  $(this).children(".b").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "top": "0px"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).children(".b").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "top": "-40px"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```